# How to create a gif from an image sequence without dither with FFMPEG?

Tags: image-processing, video, ffmpeg, gif

I'm able to create a gif from the image sequence, but I'm struggling to remove the dither from it.

This is the command I'm using to create the gif:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 24 -y -i image_%d.png -loop -1 "C:\Users\agetr\Documents\_tmp\__giuf.gif"
```

And I've tried to use the `paletteuse=dither=none` filter in different ways with no luck.

P.S.: I'm very new to the ffmpeg cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `-sws_dither none` (after the `-i $file` argument, and before the output file). I've tried this on current git/master of FFmpeg and it works as expected, but on older builds (e.g. 4.4.1) this doesn't work. I don't know why exactly, so use a recent (5.0 or any version from 2022, if possible) version/build.